No output from class method
The code:
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<numeric>
using namespace std;

class Point{
   double m_x,m_y;
public:
   Point(double x=0,double y=0):m_x(x),m_y(y){}
   Point operator+(const Point b)const{return Point(m_x+b.m_x,m_y+b.m_y);}
   Point operator/(double b)const{return Point(m_x/b,m_y/b);}
   const double& X() const{return m_x;}
   const double& Y() const{return m_y;}
   friend istream& operator>>(istream &is, Point& a);
   friend ostream& operator<<(ostream &os,const Point& a);
};

istream& operator>>(istream &is, const Point&a){
  return is>>a.X()>>a.Y();
}
ostream& operator<<(ostream &os,const Point&a){
  return os<<"("<<a.X()<<","<<a.Y()<<")";
}

class PVec{
   vector<Point> m_pts;
public:
   PVec(int n):m_pts(n){}
   const Point& operator[](int k) const {return m_pts[k];}
   size_t size() const {return m_pts.size();}
   Point sum()const{return accumulate(m_pts.begin(),m_pts.end(),Point());}
   Point avg()const{return sum()/m_pts.size();}
};

istream& operator>>(istream &xin,PVec&a){
   for(int k=0;k<a.size();k++)xin>>a[k];
   return xin;
}
ostream& operator<<(ostream &xout,const PVec&a){
   return xout<<"sum:"<<a.sum()<<endl<<"avg:"<<a.avg()<<endl;
}

int main(){
   int n;cin>>n;
   PVec pts(n);
   cin>>pts;
   cout<<pts<<endl;
   return 0;
}

Input:
7 89 95 11 10 18 10 88 10 21 67 46 53 58 50

Expected output:
sum:(331,295)
avg:(47.2857,42.1429)

Actual output: none
I tried debugging and there are no bugs, but the output is just null.

It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: How to debug small programs and Debugging Guide

What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems

I'm surprised int actually builds... xin >> a[k] should not work when you only have const Point& operator[](int k) const Same problem with the Point input stream operator.

Also, don't add newline in your stream output  operator <<. That's up to the caller of the function.

A side note: What's the problem with "using namespace std;"?.

@Someprogrammerdude Actually, gcc outputs a very helpful warning that operator>> is infinitely recursive, which is a nice hint to both "why it compiles" and "why it crashes".

Note that your declaration and definition of the overloaded friend function operator>> are different. The declaration has no const for the second parameter Point &a while the definition has a const for that parameter const Point &a. That is you're missing a const in the declaration

Also since operator>> is a friend, there's no point in using the getters/setters  method inside the friend function. That is instead of  is>>a.X() you can write is>>a.m_x. Note, the second parameter of overloaded operator>> shouldn't be const since you usually want to change its state.

I tried debugging This is where you made the largest mistake. To effectively debug you need to get the debugger to step 1 line then you need to look at your variables and flow and repeat until you see something unexpected. Your failure was you ran your code in the debugger instead of actively debugging. Just running your code in the debugger is unlikely to help.

I tried debugging and there are no bugs -- But you see there have been at least two answers that are visible right now proving there are bugs.  You have not accepted either one of the answers (so far).

The constructor
Point(double x=0,double y=0):m_x(x),m_y(y){}

Is two-in-one constructor: default and implicit converting constructor. Implicit converting constructors are almost always error prone and must be avoided if there are no specific reasons to keep it. Particularly, it causes the infinite recursion in the operator>>
istream& operator>>(istream &is, const Point&a){
  return is>>a.X()>>a.Y();
}
// implements
istream& operator>>(istream &is, const Point&a){
  return is>>Point(a.X())>>Point(a.Y());
}

Declare the constructor explicit
explicit Point(double x=0,double y=0):m_x(x),m_y(y){}

And you will catch the errors in the code. All issues started from that implicit two-in-one constructor.

The friend operator>> declaration and definition are deafferent. The latter is incorrect, since it expects to modify its argument, fixed:
istream& operator>>(istream &is, Point&a) {


a.X() and a.Y() are references to constant values, may not be used in the operator. The friend operator may access the class members directly:
istream& operator>>(istream& is, Point& a) {
  return is >> a.m_x >> a.m_y;
}


Exactly the same issue with
const Point& operator[](int k) const { return m_pts[k]; }

that should be a
Point& operator[](int k) { return m_pts[k]; }



The working code as expected: https://godbolt.org/z/6MxhdGe3P

The first problem is that the declaration and definition that you've provided for the overloaded operator>> are different because their second parameter differs in low-level const. In particular, the declaration operator>>(istream &is, Point& a) has no low-level const for the parameter a while the implementation that you're trying to provide outside the class operator>>(istream &is, const Point& a) has a const for the second parameter a.
Thus, first step is to remove the const from the second parameter.

Moreover, you also need to make the return type of overloaded operator[] to be Point& instead of const Point&. Further, the overloaded operator[] needs to be non-const because we can't bind rvalue to non-const lvalue ref.
After all the three modifications, the program looks liks:
class Point{ 
   double m_x,m_y;
public:
   
   friend istream& operator>>(istream &is, Point& a);
   
};
//------------------------------v------------>removed const from here
istream& operator>>(istream &is, Point&a){
   //use m_x and m_y directly since it is a friend function
   return is >> a.m_x>>a.m_y;   
      
} 
class PVec{
   vector<Point> m_pts;
public: 
   PVec(int n):m_pts(n){}
   //removed const from here from 2 places  
    Point& operator[](int k)  {return m_pts[k];}
   size_t size() const {return m_pts.size();}
   Point sum()const{return accumulate(m_pts.begin(),m_pts.end(),Point());}
   Point avg()const{return sum()/m_pts.size();}
};

Working demo
